# SQL Server 2008 filter conditions in stored procedure script

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to have array of characters/strings to omit the condition as below in the stored procedure

```
if(charindex(@strfileName, ' ')) <=0 and if(charindex(@strfileName, '-') <= 0) and
if(charindex(@strfileName, '-') <= 0) and if(substring(@strfileName, 'report ') <= 0)
```

What is the best way to do it,through array/list of filtering conditions?

Thanks,

Comment: charindex will not return a negative number. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

For "array of chars" you may use `LIKE`:

```
IF @strfileName NOT LIKE '%[ -!:?]%'
AND @strfileName NOT LIKE '%report%'
```

and `PATINDEX` which works similar to `CHARINDEX` but supports patterns:

```
DECLARE @strfileName VARCHAR(100) = 'asdf!xxx'

IF PATINDEX('%[ -!:?]%', @strfileName) > 0
    PRINT 'bad name'
ELSE
    PRINT 'good name'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the CharIndex input arguments in the reverse order

Please check following SQL script which returns the value if it does not contain any of the ban list ( space, '-','.' and 'report')

```
declare @strfileName nvarchar(max) = N'kodyazcom'

select @strfileName 
where
charindex(' ', @strfileName) <= 0 and 
charindex('-', @strfileName) <= 0 and
charindex('.', @strfileName) <= 0 and 
charindex('report ', @strfileName) <= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with table and test using exists(select ...

```
Declare @tableVerify table (charTest char, strTest varchar(100))
declare @strfileName varchar(100) 
set @strfileName = 'file-01.doc'

insert into @tableVerify values (' ', 'report')
insert into @tableVerify values ('-', 'data')

if exists(select * from @tableVerify where not CHARINDEX(charTest, @strfileName) <= 0)
begin
    Select '2'
end
else
begin
    Select 'e'
end
```